# Pantheon does not work on elementary OS installed with QEMU on Windows 10

Tags: pantheon, xorg

I've just installed elementary OS with **QEMU on Windows 10** with the following command :

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -accel hax -drive file=cg-box.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202.iso -m 8G -L Bios -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -boot menu=on -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -parallel none -serial none -name cg-box -no-acpi -no-hpet -no-reboot

qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -usbdevice mouse: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -usbdevice keyboard: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead
```

into a 200 GB qemu image and the installation went ok,except for one thing : I don't know how to start the desktop manager ! I tried with **"startx"**,but it gives this error message :

[image: 1]

I suspect that I should configure X,but I don't know how. Check below what's inside the **xorg.conf.new** file :

[image: 2]

Comment: Elementary OS has a tendency to be a bit wonky in VM. Personally I have good experiences with using it in VirtualBox, but I can make no promises that it will work.

Comment: I'm working on a project that involves the usage of qemu.